AWS Amplify Social Login (Google) cookies issue
Im unable to create the session cookies for the Social Login.
Funny thing is that the session is workin with email and password but not when social login is made.
In Localhost enviroment the cookies work tought.
The cookie behaivor needs to be created for domain like a usual login request.
const isLocalhost = window.location.hostname === "localhost";

export const cookieConfiguration = { 
    domain: isLocalhost ? 'localhost' : 'mydomain',
    secure: !isLocalhost, // Use true for HTTPS, false for HTTP
    sameSite: isLocalhost ? 'lax' : 'none',
};

import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

// project import
import router from 'routes';
import ThemeCustomization from 'themes';

import Locales from 'components/Locales';
import RTLLayout from 'components/RTLLayout';
import ScrollTop from 'components/ScrollTop';
import Snackbar from 'components/@extended/Snackbar';
import Notistack from 'components/third-party/Notistack';

// auth provider
// import { JWTProvider as AuthProvider } from 'contexts/JWTContext';
// import { FirebaseProvider as AuthProvider } from 'contexts/FirebaseContext';
import { AWSCognitoProvider as AuthProvider } from 'contexts/AWSCognitoContext';
// import { Auth0Provider as AuthProvider } from 'contexts/Auth0Context';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { awsconfig } from 'aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
import { CookieStorage } from 'aws-amplify/utils';
import { cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider } from '@aws-amplify/auth/cognito';
import { cookieConfiguration } from 'cookies';
cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(new CookieStorage(cookieConfiguration));

// ==============================|| APP - THEME, ROUTER, LOCAL ||============================== //
import 'react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeCustomization>
      <RTLLayout>
        <Locales>
          <ScrollTop>
            <AuthProvider>
              <>
                <Notistack>
                  <RouterProvider router={router} />
                  <Snackbar />
                </Notistack>
              </>
            </AuthProvider>
          </ScrollTop>
        </Locales>
      </RTLLayout>
    </ThemeCustomization>
  );
};

export default App;

My Component for the code response:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify/utils';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getCurrentUser } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

const SocialContext = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOAuthResponse = async () => {
      try {
        // Completing the OAuth flow manually
        const { username, userId, signInDetails } = await getCurrentUser();
        if(username){
            await fetchAuthSession({ forceRefresh: true });
            navigate('/dashboards/analytics', {
                state: { from: location.pathname }
            });
        }else{
          navigate('/login', {
            state: { from: location.pathname }
        });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('OAuth flow failed', error.message);
        navigate('/login', {
            state: { from: location.pathname }
        });
      }
    };
    handleOAuthResponse();
  }, []);
};

export default SocialContext;

It only seems to work with the same Cognito App Integration with redirect url for localhost but not for a live domain.
mydomain.com/auth/session/external/signin?code=zzzzz-9ca9-4f0a-b016-319f270ec78c&state=zzzzzzz
This example of the response code do nothing on live domain with the component so ,getCurrentUser doesnt bring any data and no cookies are created.
aws-exports.js
export const awsconfig = {
    aws_project_region: 'us-east-1',
    aws_cognito_identity_pool_id: 'us-east-1:xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xx',
    aws_cognito_region: 'us-east-1',
    aws_user_pools_id: 'us-east-xxx',
    aws_user_pools_web_client_id: 'xxxxxx',
    oauth: {
        domain: 'custom-domain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
        scope: ['email', 'openid', 'profile', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
        redirectSignIn: 'https://mydomain/auth/session/external/signin',
        redirectSignOut: 'https://mydomain/auth/session/external/logout',
        responseType: 'code',
        options: {
            prompt: 'select_account' // Force account selection
        },
    }
};

